# Does Argo workflow support HTTP invoke without creating a new pod?

Tags: argo-workflows, argoproj

In the use of Argo Workflows, we have a scenario to call the existing microservices. We can make an HTTP call through a script, but this method creates a new pod each time, which takes a long time. Wanted to know if it's good practice to do that and what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide more details? If you just need to hit an API, an Argo Workflow is probably overkill. What triggers the need for an HTTP call (user interaction, event, cron job...)? Does the workflow need to do anything besides simply make the HTTP call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Argo Workflow will always create at least one pod. You're right that this is probably excessive if the only purpose of your Workflow is to make an HTTP call.

For something lighter-weight, check out Argo Events. You can [configure an EventSource](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/concepts/event_source/), choosing from a wide variety of input sources hopefully building something very similar to whatever you're using to kick off the Argo Workflow. Then you can [configure a Trigger to make an HTTP call](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/triggers/http-trigger/).